# Not able to load Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=1.8.0.0, ............. Local works fine

Tags: azure, azure-storage

After publishing the cloud based application (web role) from visual studio, application gives following error on accessing the landing page.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Locally the same application works fine. I have kept the reference of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Copy Local attribute to True in its property while publishing the site.

I am using AzureSDK 2.0 and have reference of all storage services of version 2.0 in the reference folder.

I also have following in my web.config file.

Still am getting the above error. Please suggest how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the references section in Visual Studio and mark all the Azure DLLs as Copy Local = "True" - the Azure SDK DLLs need to be included in the bin directory they are not GACed.

If that fails, add an assembly binding redirect to the web.config...

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime"
         publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: As mentioned in my post, i have already done that. all the azure dll are marked as copy local = "True". Still facing same issue.